# SATA in Samsung Exynos

Tags: hardware, computer-architecture, system-on-chip, sata

Please take a look at the picture below.

[image]

You can see that Samsung integrates SATA 3 into the Exynos 5 Dual. So does that mean that smartphones which use Exynos 5 will be able to connect to hard drives or optical drives by using SATA interface ? Do I misunderstand anything ?

And also, does DMA in the figure ("32x DMA") refer to "Direct Memory Accessing" ?

Answer (score 2):

> So does that mean that smartphones which use Exynos 5 will be able to connect to hard drives or optical drives by using SATA interface ?

In theory, yes.

In practice, the SATA interface will most likely never be exposed. If it is not used internally by the phone or tablet, it will probably be unavailable — if you were hoping for a phone with an eSATA port, sorry, but that's very unlikely to happen. (The connector would hardly even fit on most modern phones.)

> And also, does DMA in the figure ("32x DMA") refer to "Direct Memory Accessing" ?

"Direct Memory Access", but yes. Specifically, it means that the CPU can manage up to 32 concurrent DMA transfers to/from peripherals at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So what are some function of SATA in the internal of the smartphone ? I mean why do they even integrate SATA into the phone at the first place ?

Comment: A smartphone or smartphone-like tablet is unlikely to use SATA for anything (even if the processor supports it). On the other hand a TV set top box is far more likely to want a hard drive.